# How can I make my flask + sqlite3 application threadsafe

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, thread-safety, non-thread-safe

I am attempting to build a python Flask + sqlite3 application. However I can't make it behave. I'm trying to make it threadsafe and that isn't working. I receive the error below:

```
resp = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 2532 and this is thread id 17052.
```

```
import sqlite3
from queue import Queue
from threading import Lock
from flask import Flask, redirect

class SQLiteConnectionPool:
    def __init__(self, max_connections=5):
        self.max_connections = max_connections
        self.connections = Queue(maxsize=max_connections)
        self.lock = Lock()

    def get_connection(self):
        with self.lock:
            if self.connections.qsize() < self.max_connections:
                conn = sqlite3.connect("./server/data/database.db")
                self.connections.put(conn)
            return self.connections.get()

    def release_connection(self, conn):
        self.connections.put(conn)


pool = SQLiteConnectionPool()



app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = pool.get_connection()

    resp = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    print(resp)

    pool.release_connection(conn)
    return redirect("/")


app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Please let me know if this is even possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I would rather recommend using using flask-sqlalchemy or sqlalchemy, and you will not need to handle the connections manually

Comment: Alright fantastic ill do that. Thanks.

Comment: Is flask-sqlalchemy applicable for a fresh social media platform with about 500 concurrent users?